# How to get Java running parameters from Spring Boot running inside container in pod where no ps exist

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, process

I like to get the parameters of running Java process running inside pod. When Bash ssh inside the container I can't do:

```
bash-4.4$ ps
bash: ps: command not found
```

Also looping through all procs give me too much process ids with no hint regarding the Java process. I'm doing it using this:

```
for di in $(ls -1 /proc/*); do  echo "$di"; done
```

results in me 1106 running process which I can't do cat on them when running.

Also when invoking:

```
ash-4.4$ jcmd -l
bash-4.4$
```

I still get nothing.

Comment: Maybe something like `for di in $(ls -1 /proc/*); do  cat "/proc/$di/cmdline" 2>/dev/null && echo "" ; done`  the spaces will be missing in the commandlines but that should give you a hint !

Comment: it will run all over the 1106  process

Comment: The container should only be running a single process (it won't for instance be running an sshd).  What are you trying to find out?  Is this information from the Dockerfile or the Kubernetes manifest?

Comment: @DavidMaze i like to know with what parameter the java process started from within the  container